# Remove null value from result

Tags: mysql

I have this query which is below.
How can I remove null-value from result of query?
So that only one line is left

```
SELECT
    CASE
WHEN department = 'РФ' THEN
    avg_time
END AS `РФ`,
 CASE
WHEN department = 'ЕС' THEN
    avg_time
END AS `ЕС`,
 CASE
WHEN department = 'Аутсорс' THEN
    avg_time
END AS `Аутсорс`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            department,
            (sum(apruv) / count(*) * 100) AS avg_time
        FROM
            report_designer
        WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(
            MINUTE,
            createdtime_spec,
            first_status_change
        ) <= 15
        GROUP BY
            department
    ) x
```

result of query is [image: result]

How can I remove null-value from result of query?
So that only one line is left

Comment: That will return inconsistent values. E.g. if a department has `null` PO but not null `EC` then applying the above transformation will return not null `PO` value which will be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT (sum(apruv) / count(*) * 100) AS avg_time
    FROM report_designer
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,createdtime_spec,first_status_change) <= 15
      AND department = 'РФ') AS `РФ`,
    (SELECT (sum(apruv) / count(*) * 100) AS avg_time
    FROM report_designer
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,createdtime_spec,first_status_change) <= 15
      AND department = 'EC') AS `EC`,
    (SELECT (sum(apruv) / count(*) * 100) AS avg_time
    FROM report_designer
    WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,createdtime_spec,first_status_change) <= 15
      AND department = 'Аутсорс') AS `Аутсорс`;
```